# How do I unbind something?

Tags: spiral-knights

I've finally convinced someone to play Spiral Knights with me.  Naturally, I want to help them along, so I want to give them a 2-star gun I have.  I'm currently using a 3-star gun so no loss to me, and it beats my friends default 1-star gun.

Just one hitch: It's bound to me.  I can't give it to him.

Can I unbind it?  If so, how?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't.  In most games like this items, once bound, cannot be unbound. Either that or it will be detrimentally expensive and cost real life currency or something.

Comment: @yx. Turns out you're right.  Again.  :P

Comment: I'd rather not be, but that's the drawback of those FTP games :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you're in a bad place.

> [It can only be unbound by Vise, the unbinding smith in the Bazaar.](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Binding)

Which doesn't sound so bad by itself, but [it's incredibly expensive and the item would lose all heat](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Vise).

How expensive is incredibly expensive?

- A ticket to unbind a 1 Star item - 100 crystal energy
- Unbind 2 Star Ticket - 200 CE
- Unbind 3 Star Ticket - 600 CE
- Unbind 4 Star Ticket - 1800 CE
- Unbind 5 Star Ticket - 4000 CE